# Fixed display area

Tags: html

i have a display area comprising of three div element. Two div's are fixed to the screen on either side of the larger div which sits in the middle. I want all my web pages to display in the central larger div without losing the fixed DIVs. Illustration as follows

```
<div id="outer">
        <div id="fixed_one" class="two-columns">
            button
            button
            button
        </div>
        <div id="main_display" class="ten-columns">
            Web content
            Web content
        </div>
        <div id="fixed_two" class="two-columns">
            button
            button
            button
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to i get different links to display in the middle div.

Comment: Use an `iFrame`, perhaps?

Comment: Javascript innerHTML? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#outer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

#fixed_one {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#fixed_two {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}

#main_display {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Thanx. Like that, but with #fixed_one and #fixed_two remaining fixed on the edges of the sreen even when the screen colupses. All the web pages will display in #main_display without affecting or losing the #fixed DIVs.